# Email verification with Xverify

Tags: php

I am using API of Xverify for email verifiation

Below is my API code:

```
require 'XverifyClientAPI.php';
$api_key = 'myapikey'; // Your API Key
$options = array();
$options['type'] = 'json'; // API response type
$options['domain'] = 'addeddomainname';// Reruired your domain name 
$client = new XverifyClientAPI($api_key,$options);

$data = array();
$data['email'] = 'test@xverify.com';
$client->verify('email',$data);
echo '<pre>';
echo "valid: ", var_dump($client->is_valid()), "\n";
echo "status: ", $client->status(), "\n";
print_r($client->getReponseAsObject());// Convert the json response into object
```

Here I have use API key which is provided in my xverify account and domain name which is added in my xverify account

but still its give me error like below 
valid: bool(false)

status: bad_request

```
stdClass Object
(
    [syntax] => 1
    [handle] => test
    [domain] => xverify.com
    [catch_all] => unknown
    [address] => test@xverify.com
    [error] => 0
    [status] => bad_request
    [responsecode] => 504
    [message] => Reach the API Limit
    [duration] => 0.013515949249268
)
```

I am not getting what is the problem with this ,can any body help me ?

Comment: You've reached the API limit apparently, so there's not much you can do. Maybe get a second API to do more tests.

Comment: i didn't found second api for xverify

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct url to call the api, in my case i had to the the domian name `us.xverify.com` to make it work, before i was using only xverify.com which always gave me the result same as yours(api limit reached), to check the correct api call log in to your xverify account and then click on setting and select email and scroll to the bottom of the page and check the correct url. If the id was created in the us i guess you have to use us.xverify.com